# Ruby on rails embed button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I go this so far. When I click on the logo I want the textarea to show like a modal. For e.g. http://www.leedsbuildingsociety.co.uk/resources/kick-my-habits/. Doesn't have to be that slick. I just want it with simple CSS.

I'm not sure how to go about doing it. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<a href="#"> embed </a>
    <textarea>
   <%= raw(link_to (image_tag :'http://okehamptonbowls.co.uk/wp/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Happy-Face.jpg'), root_url) %>
</textarea>
```

Comment: What do you mean by the "source code" here?  And what do you mean by "embed"?  do you just mean an img tag?  Because that's not really an embed as such - an embed would normally pull something in from another site via an iframe.

Comment: Just to clarify my previous comment, i think you should add to your question (not a comment) A) the html for the embed B) what you want to appear in the popup and C) a short description of what you mean by "popup".

Comment: Sorry I've updated my question. Hopefully its clear now

Answer (score 1):

From a form:

```
<%= f.submit "Comment", :type => :image, :src => "/images/comment-button.png" %>
```

or something like this

```
<div id="comment-button"><p>
<%= image_submit_tag("comment-button.png") %></p>
</div>
```

if you just want a button that just acts like a simple link :

```
<%= link_to image_tag(image_url, :class => "img"), link_path %>
```

Other solutions include Bootstrap glyphicons, symbol cdn , etc

For example for one of my facebook login buttons with bootstrap cdn :

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-active"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> <%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook), class: "face-btn" %></button>
```

Hope that it helps